# How to order dropdown list in QuerySelectField

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have a python wtforms QuerySelectField which pulls data from an unordered database. How do I make the list appear in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply an ordering to the query used by the field. Given a model such as

```
class Car(Base):
    ...
    make = Column(Unicode, nullable=False)
    model = Column(Unicode, nullable=False)
```

you'd pass a [query or a query factory](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields) that produces ordered results:

```
def cars():
    return session.query(Car).order_by(Car.make, Car.model)

class Cars(Form):
    car = QuerySelectField(query_factory=cars)
```

Alternatively you could set the query dynamically in a view, if not using factories:

```
form.car.query = session.query(Car).order_by(Car.make, Car.model)
```

If your models lack a descriptive string representation, you can customize the label used when rendering the options, so that the order is more apparent:

```
def get_car_label(car):
    return f"{car.make} {car.model}"

class Cars(Form):
    car = QuerySelectField(query_factory=cars, get_label=get_car_label)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it was the perfect answer. I am still learning python so this was a great help.